# Add a category from main app to Apple watch extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I develop the app with Apple Watch support.

I made a category `UIColor+FFUtils.h` where I defined the colors for my app.  So I would like to use this category in my Apple Watch extension to color the interface elements in app colors.

So, I added to the compiling sources of Apple Watch Extension target file `UIColor+FFUtils.h` and in my watch app in one controller I addd

```
#import "UIColor+FFUtils.h"
```

but now the compiler shows some errors during the category implementation compilation like this:

```
Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIColor'
Use of undeclared identifier 'UIColor'
```

I tried to add to the linked frameworks `CoreGraphics`, `UIKit`.. But the compiling error still present.

How can I solve this error? .. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this. Somehow in my category implementation Xcode didn't include `#import "UIColor+FFUtils.h"`. After this everything looks good.

Comment: I had this exact problem, and this was the solution. Thanks!